# Change from blogger to wordpress

Tags: plugins, posts, blog, plugins-url, blogger

I would like to change my blog platform from blogger to wordpress.

My website is: http://www.hdpeak.net

I would like to keep a similar template and all the posts.

What are the necessary steps I need to take?

Please be specific since I do not want to lose any content of my site.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There are already [several comprehensive guides](https://www.google.com/search?q=migrate%20blogger%20to%20wordpress) out there for this sort of migration: [Example 1](http://www.reviewzntips.com/moving-from-blogger-to-wordpress/) | [Example 2](http://www.reviewzntips.com/moving-from-blogger-to-wordpress-part-two/). I'm unfamiliar with migrating blogger templates, but I don't think all themes port over unless the theme's designer created them that way. FWIW, I think your question lacks research therefore you may not get the greatest answer. You may consider [thoroughly searching for an answer](

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same custom domain for WordPress blog.

Steps to follow (if you want to go with self hosted WordPress):

1. First purchased a hosting for WordPress from any hosting company.
2. Install WordPress on temporary URL provided in hosting account.
3. Import all the posts and comments from blogger.com blog by using default imported tool present in WordPress dashboard.
4. Follow remaining steps mentioned in [this article](http://rtcamp.com/tutorials/migrate-from-blogger-to-wordpress-best-diy-tutorial/).
5. Change the DNS in domain registrar for hosting account.
6. Final step, change WordPress URL from temporary to custom domain.

**Note:** If you want to same design like your blogger blog in WordPress, then you may need to hire some theme developer professional.

Hope above steps helpful to you.